# PCA scikit-learn - ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs

Tags: scikit-learn, pca

I use PCA from from sklearn.decomposition to reduce data dimension.

```
    pca = PCA(n_components=pca_components, whiten=True, svd_solver='full')
    y = pca.fit_transform(x)
```

The numpy array shape is (512, 48), dtype is float64. The minimum value in the array is 0.0, the maximum value is 1.7976931348623157e+308. The array does not contain infs or NaNs but I get an error

```
ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs
```

I have looke for reasons of this error and found nothing useful for me.
I suppose that maybe the maxim value in the array is too large for PCA. But I still do not know how deal with it.
Could you advice me something. Thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the issue is a combination of `whiten=True` and the largest value equal to the largest possible value of a `float64`.

From [scikit-learn's PCA docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html):

> When True (False by default) the components_ vectors are multiplied by
>   the square root of n_samples…

That creates an overflow issue which results in the `ValueError` exception.